# Excel table formatting for alternate row colours that get inherited

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel table formatted to use excel table design which has alternate colours on rows. When I click in a cell and select insert table row above or below; I get a new row but the alternate colours are not inherited.
Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Select your table and use the Insert > Table button, to ensure that it is recognised as a table in Excel.

[image]

Once you have done this, click on a cell in the table and you will see the 'Design' tab, choose an option from the 'Table Styles' selection, this will give you your alternating colours.

[image]